# factoring the Gram determinant (of a trace-form) of a semi-simple algebra

Tags: representation-theory

Begin with a finite-dimensional, complex, semi-simple algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Label
its irreducible representations using an index set $\Lambda$ and for $\lambda \in \Lambda$ let $X^{\lambda}$ denote the corresponding irreducible character. Select
complex parameters $s_\lambda$ and define a symmetric pairing (i.e. *trace-form*) on $\mathcal{A}$ by

\begin{equation} \langle u ,v \rangle \, := \, \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \, s_\lambda
\, X^\lambda \, (uv) \end{equation}

This pairing will be non-degenerate if and only if the parameters $s_\lambda$ are
non-vanishing; equivalently the pairing is non-degenerate if and only if the
Gram-determinant $G_B = \det \big( \langle b_i, b_j \rangle \big)$ is non-vanishing 
for any basis choice $\{b_1, \dots, b_N \}$ of the algebra. Now fix a basis $B = \{b_1, \dots, b_N \}$ for $\mathcal{A}$ and view the parameters $s_\lambda$ as indeterminants: In this case the Gram-determinant $G_B$ may be considered an element within the polynomial ring $\Bbb{C}\big[s_\lambda \, \big| \, \lambda \in \Lambda \big]$; moreover, bearing a scalar factor $F$ depending on the choice of basis and the character values of the algebra, $G_B$ must be a **monomial** owing to my remark about non-degeneracy.

**Question:** What are the exponents $p_\lambda$ in the monomial
expansion $G_B = F \cdot \prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \, s_{\lambda}^{p_\lambda}$ ?

Is there a reference where this is explained ?

ines.

Comment: I evicted this question from MathOverFlow and relocated it here. best, ines.

Comment: Shouldn't $p_\lambda$ be the dimension $n_\lambda$ of the representation affording the character $X^\lambda$ ? We are free to pick whatever basis of $B$ we want; in particular, we can pick the "seminormal" basis consisting of the elementary matrices $E^\lambda_{i,j}$ corresponding to the Artin-Wedderburn decomposition $\mathcal{A} \cong \prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \mathbb{C}^{n_\lambda \times n_\lambda}$. In this basis, your bilinear form is represented by a permutation matrix.

Comment: Won't it be $n_\lambda^2$ in that case ?

Comment: Oh, of course, sorry. I should have noticed the degree didn't match...